# Метод класса Calendar

Tags: java

Не пойму почему этот код :

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2004,0,14,16,40);
    System.out.println(c.get(c.HOUR_OF_DAY));
```

Выводит в консоль число **16**, что верно, ведь я установил время в **16:40**. Но если убрать `c.get()`, вот так:

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2004,0,14,16,40);
    System.out.println(c.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

То на выхлопе получаю число **11**
Почему так? Если я правильно понимаю, да и в документации написано что это `HOUR_OF_DAY` статическая целочисленная финализированная константа. Она не хранит текущее время?

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, получается это просто флаг, с удобным названием и вместо него можно напрямую передавать число 11. А не подскажете можно ли где то посмотреть исходник класса GregorianCalendar? Хотелось бы посмотреть на его реализацию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Константа, в силу своего определения, не может хранить текущее время - это ПОСТОЯННАЯ величана.

`HOUR_OF_DAY` - по факту метка, удобная для восприятия человеком, за собой она [скрывает число-константу 11](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY) - удобная уже для обработки программой форма.

В первом случае вы обращаетесь к методу  `get()`класса календарь, с запросом определенного значения. То, какое значение требуется предоставить, метод определяет по переданной константе, в данном случае - 11.
Для удобства человека она имеет метку-имя - `HOUR_OF_DAY`, что избавляет человека от запоминания того, что надо передать в метод число 11, чтобы получить часы.

Во втором случае вы просто получаете значение константы, оно всегда одинаковое.

**UPD**

класс `Calendar` относится к пакету `java.util` посмотреть исходники можно, например, на *GrepCode*: [Calendar](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Calendar.java) , [GregorianCalendar](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar) - так как тут наиболее удобная система навигации.
Кроме того, IDE обычно тоже имеет исходники API, достаточно кликнуть на интересующем классе и в контекстном меню выбрать (для Android Studio/IDEA):   `Go To -> Declaration` или нажать на интересующем классе  <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>